# Table name and database name used to for the images stored on the the extenal SD card in android

Tags: android, database, image, sd-card

Just want to verify this,  is it correct that for the sqlite database that is used with android content provider for images stored on the SD card android external memory,  for this,  the table name is called: images  and the database name is called something like in my case  external7e82312,  getting that from the name I see on the file, external7e82312.db.

If someone walked up to you on the street holding a gun and pointing it at you while asking these questions, would your answer be the same?

I am sure that the database name and table name is needed if I want to access information for the database like for the display name of the picture, time the picture was taken and other columns connected to the database

Answer (score 0):

yes if someone asks me on the street holding a gun and pointing it at me, I will answer the same.
 The database is external.db
and  table name is images.